# uib-popover-template not showing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use a `uib-popover-template` on a font awesome icon as a sort of settings menu but can't get the popup to show. This is in the header of the page I am using:

```
    <h3>{{vm.title}}
      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v pull-right"
          aria-hidden="true"
          uib-popover-template="'options-panel.html'"
          popover-placement="left"></i>
    </h3>
```

And i have the ellipses in the right corner kind of like a 'more options' menu. `options-panel.html` is just 4-5 `<select>` dropdowns depending on the page that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="viwemode">View&nbsp;Mode</label>
    <select id="viewmode"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.currentViewer"
        ng-options="view for view in vm.views"
        ng-change="vm.viewChange();"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12"
      ng-repeat="viewOption in vm.genericOptions">
    <label for="{{viewOption.label}}">{{viewOption.label}}</label>
    <select id="{{viewOption.label}}"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.config[viewOption.label]"
        ng-options="v as k for (k,v) in viewOption.values"
        ng-change="vm.optionChange(viewOption.label);"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12"
      ng-repeat="viewOption in vm.viewerOptions">
    <label for="{{viewOption.label}}">{{viewOption.label}}</label>
    <select id="{{viewOption.label}}"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.config[viewOption.label]"
        ng-options="value for value in viewOption.values"
        ng-change="vm.optionChange(viewOption.label);"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And lastly in the controller for the class I just have this object which has the template url in it:

```
vm.popover = {
  template: '<a href uib-popover-template="\'options-panel.html\'" popover-placement="left"></a>'
};
```

I am not sure what I am missing but not even a popover will show let alone the one with my template in it. If I just do the ellipses (fa-icon) with `uib-popover="test"` the popover will show with 'test' in it so I **do** have the uib dependency correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this [uib-popover-template](http://plnkr.co/edit/AlVlpp4WSVBW3cyrfWke?p=preview) plunker

I don't know your data structure but should work.

You don't need anymore

```
vm.popover = { 
  template: '<a href uib-popover-template="\'options-panel.html\'" popover-placement="left"></a>'
};
```

Answer (score -3):

This line

```
uib-popover-template="'options-panel.html'"
```

Should be

```
uib-popover-template="options-panel.html"
```

Notice I removed the single quotes, `uib-popover-template` accepts an expression that will evaluate to the template location on your `$scope`. by passing your template path in single quotes you are only passing a plain string as an expression.

From the [Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)

> uib-popover-template - A URL representing the location of a template to use for the popover body

Comment: I'm not sure if you were using a different version, but I just ran into a similar problem and without the single quotes, the popover didn't work. With the single quotes it actually works.

Comment: it has to have quotes, since is an angular expression. Otherwise it will try to find a scope object variable named `options-panel` with property `html`